# 'LocationError' on custom field after using a custom importer to import some dexterity based content types

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've created an importer for a custom dexterity content type. It imports the types fine, but I get 'LocationError' when I try to view the newly imported content I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module grokcore.view.components, line 140, in __call__
  Module grokcore.view.components, line 144, in _render_template
  Module five.grok.components, line 130, in render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /home/action/workspace/zeocluster/src/collective.nonprofitprogrammes/collective/nonprofitprogrammes/programme_templates/programmeview.pt
   - Line 20, Column 8
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'context/background/output'>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <Programme at /Plone2/my-content/dry-forest-conservation-programme>,
       'context': <Programme at /Plone2/my-content/dry-forest-conservation-programme>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7f60dda304e0>,
       'here': <Programme at /Plone2/my-content/dry-forest-conservation-programme>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7f60cc0673c0>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://mybox-23772.use1.actionbox.io:8080/Plone2/my-content/dry-forest-conservation-programme/programmeview>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'static': <Products.Five.metaclass.DirectoryResource12 object at 0x7f60cc073ed0>,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x8ee7550>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
       'view': <collective.nonprofitprogrammes.programme.ProgrammeView object at 0x7f60cc073bd0>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7f60cc073c10>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 147, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 97, in trustedBoboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 136, in traversePathElement
   - __traceback_info__: (u'Jam...ation.\n', 'output', [])
LocationError: (u'Jam...ation.\n', 'output')
```

Interestingly visiting the url of the content type followed by /edit works and after saving the changes the view works.

Comment: can you share your programmerview.pt template relevant bits?

Comment: Was the RichTextValue solution below of any help? If not, we need more clues to help solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "output" portion of the LocationError message suggests that it is having trouble rendering a RichText field. Is it possible that you initialized a RichText field with something other than a RichTextValue?

You cannot just assign a string to a RichText field. It requires a RichTextValue:

```
from plone.app.textfield.value import RichTextValue
context.body = RichTextValue(u"Your text here, in HTML")
```

See the [Dexterity Developer's Manual section on RichTextValue](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/advanced/rich-text-markup-transformations.html#the-richtextvalue) for details. It allows you to set the input and output mime types as well as the text.

Comment: Thanks SteveM that's the solution.